# oracle sql plus spool in csv format Blank lines after certain intervals

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I am spooling to csv from oracle sql plus (calling sql from shell script) however i have tried Many option but blank lines are coming after certain intervals I am using following set variable

```
 SET TERMOUT OFF
 SET ECHO OFF
 SET LINES 32767
 SET FEEDBACK off
 SET HEADING OFF
 SET NEWPAGE NONE
 SET PAGESIZE 0
 SET TRIMSPOOL ON
 SET MARKUP HTML OFF
 SET PAGES 0

 Spool ...
 select col1||','||....
 spool off
```

Anything I am missing ? Please Help

Comment: Are you sure there are no line-breaks in your data?

Comment: how to check that , sorry  I did not know that , new to this

Comment: Test my answer and see if it is working.

Comment: there were line feed so added  REPLACE(col1||','||...., CHR(13)||CHR(10)), which have worked seem, Also there were couple of Text field in the report which were having  ""  and , so used replace to remove the "" and , to blank space and after that report output started coming properly ,           Thank you for your help

Comment: So, was the line feed in the lines the problem? Please, mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

There might be line-breaks on your data. Try this:

```
 SET TERMOUT OFF
 SET ECHO OFF
 SET LINES 32767
 SET FEEDBACK off
 SET HEADING OFF
 SET NEWPAGE NONE
 SET PAGESIZE 0
 SET TRIMSPOOL ON
 SET MARKUP HTML OFF
 SET PAGES 0

 Spool ...
 select REPLACE(col1||','||...., CHR(13)||CHR(10))
 spool off
```

Answer (score 0):

there were line feed so added  REPLACE(col1||','||...., CHR(13)||CHR(10)), which have worked seem, Also there were couple of Text field in the report which were having  ""  and , so used replace to remove the "" and , to blank space and after that report output started coming properly ,           Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

SET RECSEP OFF

It should resolve the issue and not add CLRF in the output.